# Find the big-O of the sequence $a_{0} = a_{1} = 1, a_{n} = 2a_{n - 1} - 2a_{n - 2}$

Tags: limits, asymptotics, generating-functions

Find the big-O of the sequence $a_{0} = a_{1} = 1, a_{n} = 2a_{n - 1} - 2a_{n - 2}$

I found the generating function in format of $A/B$. $B = (1 - 2x + 2x^2)$ Unfortunately, the roots are complex. How can I find the big-O of $a_{n}$ when $n$ goes to $∞$.

Comment: Isn"t that a [linear difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) that enables you to find an explicit formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roots of $x^2-2x+2=0$ are $\lambda_{1,2}=1\pm i$, and hence the general term of the form
$$
a_n=c_1 (1+i)^n+c_2 (1-i)^n
$$
In fact, $c_1=c_2=1/2$ and hence
$$
a_n=2^{n/2-1}
\left(
\mathrm{e}^{i n\pi/4}+\mathrm{e}^{-in\pi/4}
\right)=2^{n/2}\cos(n\pi/4)=\mathcal O(2^{n/2})
$$